# How to reapply after turning down a position

Tags: email, cover-letter, follow-up

I was offered a position in October 2015. I turned it down because I had been working at home for about 10 months and wasn't sure I wanted to go back to an office full time (after working in one for 20+ years). But now, six months later, I would like to reapply to the company (I'm going stir crazy at home).

I'm not sure how to word my email, and if I should send it to the HR person only, or would it be appropriate to also copy the person who would have been my supervisor (I was told he really liked me--and he told me my writing test was one of the best he's seen). I don't think there is an open position but wanted to let them know I'm available should one come up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Emailing them both can't hurt.

Why not make an office at home? I have both my formal office in town and a fully equipped workshop at home where I actually get more work done. Stir crazy isn't hard to beat unless it's the social interaction that you're missing.